# Automorphism of the following rational function

Tags: number-theory, automorphism-group, mobius-transformation

This problem corresponds to the exercise 4.39 in Silverman's book "The Arithmetic of Dynamical systems":

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}^*$, $d \geq 1$ and consider the rational function with degree $d$ $$\phi(z) = \left( \frac{z+1}{z-1} \right)^d.$$

Let $Aut(\phi) = \{ f \in PGL_2(\mathbb{C}): f \phi f^{-1} = \phi \}$ where the operation considere there is the composition of functions. Then $Aut(\phi) = \{ id \}$, i.e., the identity Mobius transformation.

MY ATTEMPTS: I have tried different things.

1. Of course the condition can also be seen as $f \phi = \phi f$. Putting a generic $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+e}$ and making equations for $a,b,c,e$ does not really help me because the exponent $d$ that appears in $\phi$.
2. Evaluating at "nice" points. There are no nice points in my opinion, because when you try to make $f \phi$ nice, $\phi f$ is ugly, and nothing good arises.
3. Observing that $\phi$ is multiplying a Mobius transformation $\psi = \frac{z+1}{z-1}$ $d$ times. I could not get anything from this idea, but maybe it can inspire someone else.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the exercise asks you to prove is false. The actual true statement is:

> Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}^\times$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2}$, and consider the rational function $\varphi\left(z\right)=\alpha\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^n$. Then $\operatorname{Aut}\left(\varphi\right)=\left\{f\in \operatorname{PGL}_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right):f\circ \varphi\circ f^{-1}=\varphi\right\}$ satisfies $$\operatorname{Aut}\left(\varphi\right)=\begin{cases}\left\{\operatorname{id}\right\},&\alpha^2\neq \left(-1\right)^{n+1},\\\left\{\operatorname{id},z\mapsto -\frac{1}{z}\right\},&\alpha^2=\left(-1\right)^{n+1}.\end{cases}$$

Observe that this is not a problem for Silverman because the only place in the book where he makes use of this, which is *Example* 4.85, he has $\alpha=i$ and $n=3$, which satisfy $\alpha^2\neq \left(-1\right)^{n+1}$.

**PROOF:** Take $f\left(z\right)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{C}$ and $ad\neq bc$, and let us work-out the equation $f\circ \varphi\circ f^{-1}=\varphi$, which is equivalent to $f\circ \varphi=\varphi\circ f$.

First let me show that neither of the polynomials$$c\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n+d\left(z-1\right)^n,$$ $$\left(a-c\right)z+b-d,$$ $$a\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n+b\left(z-1\right)^n,$$ $$\left(a+c\right)z+b+d$$ are the zero polynomial: the first being zero would imply $c\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n=-d\left(z-1\right)^n$, which by unique factorization cannot happen if either $c$ or $d$ are nonzero, thus we would get $c=d=0$, violating our assumption $ad\neq bc$. The second being zero would imply $a-c=b-d=0$, thus $a=c$ and $b=d$, again violating $ad\neq bc$. The third is nonzero by an analogous reasoning to the first, and the fourth being zero would imply $a=-c$ and $b=-d$, again contradicting $ad\neq bc$.

Now the equation $f\circ \varphi=\varphi\circ f$ becomes$$\frac{a\varphi\left(z\right)+b}{c\varphi\left(z\right)+d}=\alpha\left(\frac{f\left(z\right)+1}{f\left(z\right)-1}\right)^n,$$ $$\frac{a\alpha\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^n+b}{c\alpha\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^n+d}=\alpha\left(\frac{\frac{az+b}{cz+d}+1}{\frac{az+b}{cz+d}-1}\right)^n,$$ $$\frac{a\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n+b\left(z-1\right)^n}{c\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n+d\left(z-1\right)^n}=\alpha\left(\frac{\left(a+c\right)z+b+d}{\left(a-c\right)z+b-d}\right)^n.$$ I claim that $A\left(z\right)=a\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n+b\left(z-1\right)^n$ and $B\left(z\right)=c\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n+d\left(z-1\right)^n$ are relatively prime polynomials. Indeed, if there were an irreducible polynomial $P\left(z\right)$ dividing both, then we would have$$P\left(z\right)\mid dA\left(z\right)-bB\left(z\right)=\underbrace{\alpha\left(ad-bc\right)}_{\in\mathbb{C}^\times}\left(z+1\right)^n,$$ $$P\left(z\right)\mid aB\left(z\right)-cA\left(z\right)=\underbrace{\left(ad-bc\right)}_{\in\mathbb{C}^\times}\left(z-1\right)^n,$$ which is impossible since these two polynomials are relatively prime.

We conclude that $\frac{a\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n+b\left(z-1\right)^n}{c\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n+d\left(z-1\right)^n}=\alpha\frac{\left(\left(a+c\right)z+b+d\right)^n}{\left(\left(a-c\right)z+b-d\right)^n}$ is an irreducible fraction. Since an expression of an irreducible fraction is unique up to nonzero scalar multiplication, then there cannot be any cancellation in $\alpha\frac{\left(\left(a+c\right)z+b+d\right)^n}{\left(\left(a-c\right)z+b-d\right)^n}$, and thus $\left(\left(a+c\right)z+b+d\right)^n$ and $\left(\left(a-c\right)z+b-d\right)^n$ are also relatively prime. We conclude that there exist $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{C}^\times$ such that$$a\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n+b\left(z-1\right)^n=\lambda \left(\left(a+c\right)z+b+d\right)^n,$$ $$c\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n+d\left(z-1\right)^n=\mu \left(\left(a-c\right)z+b-d\right)^n.$$ This implies that the polynomials $a\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n+b\left(z-1\right)^n$ and $c\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n+d\left(z-1\right)^n$ cannot have more than one root.

I claim that $ab=0=cd$. Indeed, assume this is not the case. Without losing generality assume $cd\neq 0$ (the case $ab\neq 0$ is perfectly analogous). Let $\beta,\gamma,\delta\in\mathbb{C}^\times$ be $n$th roots of $\alpha,c,d$ respectively. Since $z^n+1$ is relatively prime to its derivative $nz^{n-1}$, then it has $n$ pairwise different roots $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$, and we can therefore write$$c\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n+d\left(z-1\right)^n=d\left(z-1\right)^n\left[\left(\frac{\gamma\beta}{\delta}\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^n+1\right]=$$ $$=d\left(z-1\right)^n\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{\gamma\beta}{\delta}\frac{z+1}{z-1}-\alpha_j\right)=d\prod_{j=1}^n\left[\frac{\gamma\beta}{\delta}\left(z+1\right)-\alpha_j\left(z-1\right)\right].$$ Since this is not the zero polynomial (by our first observation), then it is either a nonzero constant or a polynomial having a single root. But the former would imply $\frac{\gamma\beta}{\delta}=\alpha_j$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}_{\leq n}$ (so that we never have a nonzero linear term in the product). But $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ are pairwise different and we are assuming $n\geq 2$, so this is impossible.

Thus we have exactly one root, let us call it $\omega$. This implies that, for all $j\in\mathbb{N}_{\leq n}$,$$\frac{\gamma\beta}{\delta}\left(\omega+1\right)-\alpha_j\left(\omega-1\right)=0,$$ and since $\beta\gamma\delta\neq 0$ because $\alpha cd\neq 0$, then $\omega-1\neq 0$ and$$\alpha_j=\frac{\frac{\gamma\beta}{\delta}\left(\omega+1\right)}{\omega-1},$$ again contradicting that $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ are pairwise different and $n\geq 2$.

We conclude that $cd=0$, and by a perfectly analogous reasoning, $ab=0$. We cannot have $c=d=0$ or we violate $ad\neq bc$. Same problem occurs if $a=b=0$. We conclude that exactly one of $\left\{c,d\right\}$ is zero, and exactly one of $\left\{a,b\right\}$ is zero. But moreover, we cannot have $a=c=0$ nor $b=d=0$, since we would again be violating $ad\neq bc$, so there are only two possibilities:

**FIRST CASE**: $a\neq 0=c$. Then $b=0\neq d$ and $f\left(z\right)=\frac{a}{d}z$.

**SECOND CASE**: $a=0\neq c$. Then $b\neq 0=d$ and $f\left(z\right)=\frac{b}{cz}$.

In the first case, our expression for $f\circ \varphi=\varphi\circ f$ becomes$$\frac{a\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n}{d\left(z-1\right)^n}=\alpha\left(\frac{az+d}{az-d}\right)^n,$$ thus multiplying by $\left(z-1\right)^n\left(az-d\right)^n$ and evaluating at $z=-1$ we get $a\left(-1\right)+d=0$, giving $a=d$ and thus $f\left(z\right)=z$. It is clear that this one, being the identity, works.

In the second case, the expression becomes$$\frac{b\left(z-1\right)^n}{c\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n}=\alpha\left(\frac{cz+b}{-cz+b}\right)^n,$$ thus multiplying by $\left(z+1\right)^n\left(-cz+b\right)^n$ and evaluating at $z=1$ we get $c\cdot 1+b=0$, giving $f\left(z\right)=-\frac{1}{z}$. But this one does not always work, since the equation becomes$$-\frac{\left(z-1\right)^n}{\alpha\left(z+1\right)^n}=\alpha\left(\frac{z-1}{-z-1}\right)^n,$$ $$-\frac{1}{\alpha}=\frac{\alpha}{\left(-1\right)^n},$$ $$\alpha^2=\left(-1\right)^{n+1}.$$ Thus we must include also $z\mapsto -\frac{1}{z}$ if and only if $\alpha^2=\left(-1\right)^{n+1}$.

Comment: Nights together in conferences!